# What value does the variable in the following code snippet have?

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    let data = &[1..3];
    println!("Data is {:?}", data);
}
```

What does it mean to have `&[1..3]` as assigned value for this statement?

Comment: There is a useful trick to find out the type: `let _: () = data;`. This will cause an error that tells you the type of `data`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly:

```
let foo = &[1,2,3];
```

creates a temporary array with the same lifetime as the `foo` binding, and stores a reference to that in `foo`.

However, that's not exactly what your program is doing.  As the other answer says, it's useful to run it, and you get:

```
Data is [1..3]
```

That doesn't look like `[1,2,3]`!  We can trick the compiler into telling us what it really is by using its error messages.  We know it's definitely not `()`, so let's try that first:

```
fn main() {
    let data = &[1..3];
    let () = data;
}
```

This gives us an error on purpose which includes:

```
error: mismatched types [--explain E0308]
 --> <anon>:3:17
  |>
3 |>     let () = data;
  |>         ^^ expected &-ptr, found ()
note: expected type `&[std::ops::Range<_>; 1]`
note:    found type `()`
```

And that tells us the answer - `data` is a reference (`&`) to an array of one item (`[_;1]`), which is a [`std::ops::Range<_>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html) object.

Comment: Of course, since it's a valid pattern! Will do that next time, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are expecting `data` to be of type `&[i32; 2]`; it isn't. In times like these, when you are not sure, you can verify it by trying to write:

`let data: &[i32; 2] = &[1..3];`

which won't work. The error message will be something like:

```
main.rs:11:26: 11:30 error: mismatched types [E0308]
main.rs:11:26: 11:30 note: expected type `i32`
main.rs:11:26: 11:30 note:    found type `std::ops::Range<_>`
```

What you actually have here is:

`let data: &[std::ops::Range<_>] = &[1..3];`